# Getting Error: Request timed out, trying to connect to a rest based service on Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I am getting an error trying to connect to a rest service I have deployed on Kubernetes

The pods are all up and running

```
account-docker-kubernetes                   1/1     Running   0          22m   10.1.0.39   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
account-docker-kubernetes-f4457789c-446rx   1/1     Running   0          21m   10.1.0.42   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
account-docker-kubernetes-f4457789c-mzkt6   1/1     Running   0          21m   10.1.0.41   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
account-docker-kubernetes-f4457789c-q4rhg   1/1     Running   0          21m   10.1.0.40   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
```

According to docs to connect from outside you need to have a service.
my service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: account-docker-kubernetes
  labels:
    name: account-docker-kubernetes
spec:
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30163 
      port: 8082      
      targetPort: 8082  
      protocol: TCP
  selector:           
    app: account-docker-kubernetes
  type: NodePort
```

To get the port

```
C:\Users\Tony>kubectl get services
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
account-docker-kubernetes   NodePort    10.106.46.105   <none>        8082:30163/TCP   33m
kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          28h
```

Port is 30163.

To get the IP of the node.

```
C:\Users\Tony>kubectl get node -o wide
NAME             STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION                   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane,master   29h   v1.22.4   192.168.65.4   <none>        Docker Desktop   5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2   docker://20.10.11
```

The IP is 192.168.65.4

The controller is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bank")
public class AccountController {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BankController.class);
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/health/")
    public String getHealth() {
        return "UP";
    }
```

So http://192.168.65.4:30163/bank/health/ should return UP.
account-docker-kubernetes is up and running

```
C:\Users\Tony>kubectl logs account-docker-kubernetes

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)

2022-09-29 13:43:02.353  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] c.c.r.user.bankuser.BankUserApplication  : Starting BankUserApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 16.0.1 on account-docker-kubernetes with PID 1 (/app/account-docker-kubernetes.war started by root in /app)
2022-09-29 13:43:02.356  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] c.c.r.user.bankuser.BankUserApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-09-29 13:43:03.303  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=407d6cee-8092-3262-9d93-30cee0f33d9c
2022-09-29 13:43:03.929  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2022-09-29 13:43:03.941  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-09-29 13:43:03.941  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
2022-09-29 13:43:04.991  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-09-29 13:43:04.991  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2581 ms
2022-09-29 13:43:06.281  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''
2022-09-29 13:43:06.293  INFO [account-docker-kubernetes,,] 1 --- [           main] c.c.r.user.bankuser.BankUserApplication  : Started BankUserApplication in 4.657 seconds (JVM running for 5.227)
```

There must be a step I am missing. I have the IP of the node, and the port of the service.
Firewall is turned off.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

http://10.1.0.39:30163/bank/health/
-> it's not possible. because of POD_IP:NodePort.

You have to use NODE_IP:NodePort

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport

> Using a NodePort gives you the freedom to set up your own load balancing solution, to configure environments that are not fully supported by Kubernetes, or even to expose one or more nodes' IPs directly.

Comment: Thank you, you are corret, I got slightly confused

kubectl get node -o wide
NAME             STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION                   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane,master   29h   v1.22.4   192.168.65.4   <none>        Docker Desktop   5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2   docker://20.10.11

IP is http://192.168.65.4:30163/bank/health/ and still times out

Comment: I think you should add the firewall rule about inbound tcp/30163..

or try to turn off your firewall.

Comment: Turned of windows firewall defender. Still cant connect. There has to be a step I missed.

Comment: Can you share account-docker-kubernetes endpoint yaml and endpointslices yaml?

Comment: I dont have either, I only have a service.yml, and a deployment.yml that loads the image into a pod and starts the app. The tutorial does not mention those two yml files. 
maybe that is what is missing.